# After migrating to ionic v3.0.1 ionic native google-maps call to external.launchNavigation not working anymore

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I have just migrate my application from ionic v2.0.0 to v3.0.1 and I have a issue with the ionic native Google maps plugin.

Almost everything is working except the following code:

```
    if (this.destination != null) {
      plugin.google.maps.external.launchNavigation({
        "from": this.currentLocation,
        "to": this.destination
      });
```

Do you know how to update this piece of code to make it work with Ionic v3.0.1 ?

Thanks.

Regards.

Comment: _Almost everything is working except the following code_.. what happens? are you getting errors?

Comment: Are there any errors during build? Or does this fail at runtime? 
Also, do post your app.module.ts as there could be potential plugin changes.